# Is it possible to take repeated command line inputs in python untill user exits explicitly

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

```
import sys
import commands
from optparse import OptionParser

def sample():
    parser.add_option("-a", "--accept",
                            action="store",
                            dest="accept",
                            type="str",
                            help="Accept or quit")
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
    if(options.accept != None) and (options.accept == "123"):
        print "Hello! code accepted!"
    elif(options.accept == "quit"):
        break
```

So when I execute this small script in the format python sample.py -a 123, it prints Hello! code accepted! and then it exits, but I want it to repeatedly keep executing the script untill I keep executing in the format python sample.py -a 123. It should only exit when I give 'quit' in the command line options.

Current output:-

```
#python sample.py -a 123
Hello!Code accepted!
#
```

Expected output:-

```
#python sample.py -a 123
Hello!Code accepted!
python sample.py -a 123
Hello!Code accepted!
python sample.py -a 123
Hello!Code accepted!
python sample.py -a quit
#
```

Any help? Thanks

Comment: You might want to look into the input command coupled with a while loop. OptionParser is only for initialization and not Stdin reading

Comment: I tried that too, but it wasn't running the way I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python module specifically for creating command line applications -- [Cmd](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html). It was featured in PyMOTW (Python module of the week) quite a while back. With just a few lines of code you can have a complete console app with online help, autocomplete, and a REPL (read-eval-print loop). The PyMOTW article has a decent little tutorial. See http://pymotw.com/2/cmd/